# Difference between study English / in studying English

Tags: sentence-meaning, future-tense

Do these sentences mean the same 
*I will help you study English.

 I will help you in studying English.*

Comment: If you want to use a prepisition with _help_, use _with_. _"I will help you with your English"_

Comment: As @Yuri says, another option is to write: *I will help you with studying English.* After a preposition, you use the *-ing* form of the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, besides "can't help doing something", the verb *to help* is to be followed by infinitive,   you can use "help *in* doing something" referring to a continuous process, like learning a foreign language for example.

Personally, I'd sooner use *help (to)do something* for a definite  action with a  known or foreseen result.

> Help me (to) do the dishes. (definite action, known result - clean
>   dishes)

Comment: *I will help you to study English* seems perfectly natural to me as a native speaker. I don't think it matters whether or not the verb describes a continuous process.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, 'I will help you study English' is the most natural. 'I will help you in...' sounds really strange,

Comment: I agree, but please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.